# String Split by comma but ignore few parts of that

Tags: split

I have a string which contains

',jagdamba@jabonged.com, Shri Jagdamba Exports,Shri Jagdamba Exports,JAGDAMBA PEARLS,9293003601,Sri Jagdamba Pearls,"715, 7th Floor, Chenoy Trade Center, Parklane,",Secunderabad,500003,,India,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Sri Jagdamba Pearls,"715, 7th Floor, Chenoy Trade Center, Parklane",,9293003601,500003,Andhra Pradesh,INDIA,,,15th of every month,0,XYDS05381F,0,01-01-18,,,0,,,,,JBangalore PC,,,,,,,,,,,6:00 PM,40,No,,Bluedart,Bluedart,\r',

Now I want to split it by ",". But the problem comes when it splits the address as well which is also mentioned by ",". How to solve it?

Comment: I want to cut an apple but I also want the apple not to be cut

Comment: Any particular programming language or platform? most can handle quoted CSV relatively straight forwardly

Comment: Well the address seems to be different because it is in quotes (which is usually the case when the separator should be ignored) which  most tools can handle. Which tools, programming languages or framework are you using? Please improve your question so that others can help you.

Comment: var string = "1,2,3,"4,5", 6";

Output should be ["1,"2","3","4,5","6"] after split using javascript

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't, there's no magical way to detect that a comma is part of the adress.

You will need to ask whoever is creating that string to use a separator that can not be used in any of the fields so you can split based on that.